# I can't get brushing / linking to work with crosstalk and plotly for a 2 subplots when 1 subplot is an aggregate graph

Tags: r, linker, plotly, crosstalk

I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't get brushing to work for my two plots (p1,p2) below.

What I'm expecting: If I click the a specific diamond 'cut in the bar graph on the left, the corresponding cut should be highlighted in the scatterplot.

[brushing / linking NOT working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1E84.png)

Reproducible example below

```
library(crosstalk);library(tidyverse);library(plotly)

d = ggplot2::diamonds %>% slice_sample(prop = 0.01)

m <- d %>% highlight_key(~cut)
#m = crosstalk::SharedData$new(d, key = ~cut)

p1 = m$data() %>% count(cut) %>% plot_ly() %>% add_bars(x = ~cut, y = ~n, color =~cut)
p2 = m %>% plot_ly() %>% add_markers(x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~cut)

subplot(p1,p2) %>% highlight('plotly_click') %>% hide_legend()
```

This DOES, however, work if both graphs are NON-aggregate graphs.

[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQEwK.png)

```
library(crosstalk);library(tidyverse);library(plotly)

d = ggplot2::diamonds %>% slice_sample(prop = 0.01)

m <- d %>% highlight_key(~cut)
#m = crosstalk::SharedData$new(d, key = ~cut)

p1 = m %>% plot_ly() %>% add_markers(x = ~color, y = ~price, color = ~cut)
p2 = m %>% plot_ly() %>% add_markers(x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~cut)

subplot(p1,p2) %>% highlight('plotly_click') %>% hide_legend()
```

Comment: 1.3.1056 is probably the version of RStudio, not R. R is currently on v4.0.2

Comment: One thing weird is that I can't use this chain, which should work

`data_frame %>% plot_ly() %>% count(cut)`

This results in this error: 

`Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('plotly', 'htmlwidget')"`

Comment: Made a mistake, gave Rstudio version, not R

R v4.0.2  plotly v4.9.2.1 , dplyr v1.0.0

Comment: I don't use plotly often, but doesn't `plot_ly` create a plot? `dplyr::count` is going to expect a data frame, which isn't what you're giving it. Are you positive that's what you saw & what function you're remembering?

Comment: yes, absolutely, I'm sure.  Adding the image of the code above.

Comment: **Moderator Note** - Please do not overwrite a particular question that you have asked with a completely different question. [Ask a new question instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @BhargavRao sorry, my bad.  I'm remember this going forward.